# What is Package For The Web 4 ? Can we use it today to build executive file?

Tags: installshield

1 of my 80 dll's has been updated. Previously we used Packagefortheweb 4.0 to build setup. Now we need to update our client tool. How can we use Packagefortheweb to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Package for the Web is long since unsupported. If you have InstallShield you can make a compressed installation, or optionally a downloader, to do what you want. Note that PFTW primarily creates a compressed single-exe wrapper around a set of files including another exe, which (a) many tools can do these days, and (b) doesn't have any logic to update files on a target machine, so will need some sort of installation logic anyway.

Comment: Do you have any sample installation logic or so. I am looking to make a tool same as PFTW but I don't know what goes inside PFTW. What it actually does. Kindly Suggest

Comment: But Still if I want to develop a tool of my own from scratch which can generate setup.exe from a bunch of dll's. What are the possible ways I can do so.

Comment: Is there any already existing set of code/script/ open source code which can process our dll's (some 80-100 dll's) and generate a setup.exe out of it. I am building a windows application from which we can prepare setup.exe. Or if there is some other way also you can suggest some to do this task from scratch.

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off topic here, and your other follow-up question is too broad. If you resolve that, you'd be better off asking separate questions rather than commenting here, as more people will see it.

Comment: What about open source code, Is there anything like that?. I Posted this qsn because Package For Web 4 is no longer supported by installed shield and bcoz of this we r facing certain issues. so it's obvious to look for alternatives..rt?

Answer (score 0):

use iexpress under Windows Winkey+R -> iexpress

Answer (score 0):

It is real simple to use `Package for the WEB` under windows 10.

You need to create a manifest file with `asInvoker` privileges for the `pftwwiz.exe` and a `requireAdministrator` manifest for the `stub32i.exe` file.

Use the `mt.exe` tool to apply the manifest to this files.

Done!

The manifest code I use is this (the one for `stub32i.exe`), the one for the wizard just uses `asInvoker`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
  <ms_compatibility:compatibility xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <ms_compatibility:application xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
      <ms_compatibility:supportedOS xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <ms_compatibility:supportedOS xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <ms_compatibility:supportedOS xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <ms_compatibility:supportedOS xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <ms_compatibility:supportedOS xmlns:ms_compatibility="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1" Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
    </ms_compatibility:application>
  </ms_compatibility:compatibility>
</assembly>
```

The batch file I use is this (I have copies with the addition original for this files):

```
@echo off
REM -- This batch file is needed to insert the external manifest file into the EXE, otherwise the program asks for administrative rights or fails to install

copy "pftwwiz (Original).exe" pftwwiz.exe
mt -manifest pftwwiz.manifest -outputresource:pftwwiz.exe
call signit pftwwiz.exe
copy pftwwiz.exe "pftwwiz (Patched).exe" 

copy "stub32i (Original).exe" stub32i.exe
mt -manifest stub32i.manifest -outputresource:stub32i.exe
copy stub32i.exe "stub32i (Patched).exe"
```